# In Java, can one get away with using "raw unparameterised class"-es instead of using dummy interfaces?

Tags: java

It's been a while since I touched generics in Java, I have this:

```
Map<List<MyGenericType>, Set<List<MyGenericType>>> x = new HashMap<>();
```

In truth, `MyGenericType` requires a generic parameter, since it is defined like this:

```
public class MyGenericType<X> {}
```

I declared `x` with pre-emptive type-erasure of `MyGenericType` because I didn't want to make an empty marker interface just for the sake of grouping things. Will this, for the sake of having a collection, work in my favor or will I have to make a marker interface to make this possible?

(**EDIT**)
That is:

1. `public interface SomeCommonInterface {...}`
2. `MyGenericType implements SomeCommonInterface ...`
3. `Map<List<SomeCommonInterface>, Set<List<SomeCommonInterface>>> x = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Not a good idea to use `List`, i.e. mutable object, as key in a `Map`

Comment: Why do you want to use `MyGenericType` without the generic type? Why do you not add the type?

Comment: Why not use `MyGenericType<?>` if you don't know the actual type?

Comment: @Progman Because I will be inserting objects with different type parameters into the map. Sort of like having a list of `Fruit` and putting in different kinds of fruit.

Comment: @Slaw Would that work for what I'm trying to do? And if it does, what's the difference? I want to be able to insert various "types" of `MyGenericType` into the lists.

Comment: @Yousaf I actually declare the lists using `List.of` which I've been told makes an unmodifiable list. I don't like this approach either - Does Java actually support non-primitive arrays?

Comment: The `?` is a wildcard that means "can be any type [that matches the type parameter bounds]". Using a wildcard means you're still using a parameterized type, which is typically better than using a raw type. Note it will restrict you in other ways. If any method of `MyGenericType` has `X` as a parameter then you won't be able to call that method on a `MyGenericType<?>` and if any method has `X` as a return type you'll only know it to be the upper bound of `X` (though the latter is true of raw types as well, I believe).

Comment: @Slaw I see - but I still don't understand the difference between `<?>` and not having it. Edit: I see - is it just a practice to let others know that the type is actually generic?

Comment: It's the difference between having a parameterized type and a raw type. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/).

Comment: if you can have a bounded type `public class MyGenericType<X extends MyInterface> {}` and all your later operations can be driven off MyInterface. that may be easier.

Comment: @Slaw `MyGenericType<?>` isn't a bad advice, but it will not stop things like : `Map<List<MyGenericType<?>>, Set<List<MyGenericType<?>>>> x = new HashMap<>(); x.put(List.of(new MyGenericType<String>()), Set.of(List.of(new MyGenericType<Integer>())));`. there are _two_ unbounded types in the declaration, these are different types for the compiler

Comment: @Eugene Since the OP was considering using raw types I figured that's exactly the behavior they wanted.

Comment: @Slaw oh! I though exactly in reverse, since there was a type in `MyGenericType`, he wanted some safety. interesting how divergent both views are. thank you for the follow-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that `Integer` as well as `Double` both extend `Number` and in turn, `Number` extends `Object`.

A `List<Number>` is in no way usable as a `List<Integer>` **and vice versa**. `List<Number> x = new ArrayList<Integer>` **does not compile**. This is called 'invariance', and it is 'correct', because if it did compile, you could add doubles to a list of integers which is obviously not right. It tends to throw people off, though, which is why I mention it. If you want covariance or contravariance, you must *opt into this*: `List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` *does* compile. But then `list.add(5);` won't, because if it did, you would again be able to add doubles to a list of integers and that wouldn't be right.

Once you entirely omit generics on a thing, all type checking on generics is right out the door, and you don't want that. Can you 'get away with it'? Well, uh, the compiler will toss a bunch of warnings in your face and you turn off quite a bit of type checking. If you mean with 'get away with it': "Does it compile"? Yes, it does. If you mean: "Would this code pass any reasonable java coder's code review"? **No, it won't**.

Simple solution: What's wrong with using `MyGenericType<?>` here?

NB: Keys in maps should be immutable; list is not. Using it is therefore quite a bad plan; what is that supposed to represent?

Comment: I presume you meant to write `list.add(5.0)`? Can the standard java compiler not infer that `list` is actually a list of integers?

Comment: Furthermore, I want an immutable ordered collection of objects - I've since changed it to primitive arrays

Comment: @Novicegrammer Whether `list.add(5)` or `list.add(5.0)`, both would fail for a `List<? extends Number>`. And the compiler has nothing to infer; the code states explicitly that the variable type is a `List<? extends Number>`, not a `List<Integer>`. Nor would you want the compiler to infer anything. The whole reason for `List<? extends Number>` is to describe that the "real" type argument be anything that extends `Number` (e.g. `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, `List<BigDecimal>`, etc.). That's why you can't add anything to such a `List`, because you _don't know_ what the real element type is.

Comment: @Novicegrammer These Q&As may help: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/) and [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/).

Comment: to me declaring two wildcard unbounded types solves very little for the OP, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850971/in-java-can-one-get-away-with-using-raw-unparameterised-class-es-instead-of-u#comment111150051_62850971)

Comment: @Slaw so what's the point of this being legal Java if you can't add anything to it?

Comment: @Novicegrammer Flexibility. The Q&As I linked to show why you would want to do this. A `List<? extends Number>` is a _producer_ of some type of `Number`, but it can't _consume_ anything. The opposite is true of `List<? super Number>` (though it can produce `Object`). It may be more obvious if you look at things like `Function<? super T, ? extends R>` and `Consumer<? super T>` and `Supplier<? extends T>` as parameter types; without the wildcards the _users of the API_ lose flexibility. Again, the linked Q&As go into much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but as said in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850971/in-java-can-one-get-away-with-using-raw-unparameterised-class-es-instead-of-u#comment111150051_62850971), I don't think that adding wildcards solves anything.

Depending were the use-site of this `Map` is, you could have some kind of safety. I was in your shoes a couple of times, the only solution I know is to do:

```
@Getter
static class Box<T> {

    private Map<List<MyGenericType<T>>, Set<List<MyGenericType<T>>>> x = new HashMap<>();

}
```

i.e.: expose the `Map` via a "wrapper", that has a type variable defined. If callers provide a type when instantiating `Box`, you will get the needed type safety:

```
new Box<Integer>().getX().put(...); // you can only put a MyGenericType<Integer> in here now
```

Otherwise when using raw types or even `?`, you could put different type in the key and value.